# A class of sequences is of bounded variation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\left\{ a_n \right\}$ be a null sequence s.t. 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty \vert\Delta a_k\vert^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}<\infty$$
for some $p>1$.

How to prove that $\left\{ a_n \right\}$ must be of bounded variation?

My attempt: It is enough to prove that
$$\vert \Delta a_n\vert \leq \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty \vert\Delta a_k\vert^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}, \forall n>n_0, \text{for some} \; n_0 \in \mathbb{N}.$$
I've tried proving the last inequality using Jensens' inequality, but I can't get to the desired result.

Edit:
How to find a sequence $\left\{ a_n \right\}$ of bounded variation for which $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty \vert\Delta a_k\vert^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}<\infty$ doesn't hold for any $p>1$?

Comment: Just to make sure: $\Delta a_n = a_{n+1} - a_n$ (or $a_n - a_{n+1}$, which one doesn't matter since we take absolute values)?

Comment: @daniel $\Delta a_n = a_n - a_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let, as usual, $q$ denote the conjugate exponent to $p$. For each $n$, by Hölder's inequality we have
$$\sum_{k = n}^{2n-1} \lvert \Delta a_k\rvert = \sum_{k = n}^{2n-1} 1\cdot \lvert\Delta a_k\rvert \leqslant n^{1/q}\biggl(\sum_{k = n}^{2n-1} \lvert\Delta a_k\rvert^p\biggr)^{1/p},$$
that is,
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = n}^{2n-1} \lvert \Delta a_k\rvert \leqslant \biggl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = n}^{2n-1} \lvert\Delta a_k\rvert^p\biggr)^{1/p} \leqslant \biggl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = n}^{\infty} \lvert\Delta a_k\rvert^p\biggr)^{1/p}.$$
Consequently
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = n}^{2n-1} \lvert\Delta a_k\rvert < \infty.$$
Now we can change the order of summation and obtain
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \lvert\Delta a_k\rvert \sum_{k/2 < n \leqslant k} \frac{1}{n} < \infty.$$
And for every $k$ we have
$$\sum_{k/2 < n \leqslant k} \frac{1}{n} \geqslant \frac{1}{2}\,,$$
hence
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \lvert\Delta a_k\rvert \leqslant 2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = n}^{2n-1} \lvert\Delta a_k\rvert < \infty\,,$$
i.e. $(a_k)$ is of bounded variation.

With regard to the edit, note that
$$\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = n}^{\infty} \lvert\Delta a_k\rvert^p\biggr)^{1/p} \geqslant \frac{1}{n^{1/p}}\max \{ \lvert\Delta a_k\rvert : k \geqslant n\} \geqslant \frac{1}{n}\max \{ \lvert\Delta a_k\rvert : k \geqslant n\}\,.$$
Thus from any null sequence $(b_n)$ of bounded variation for which $\Delta b_n \neq 0$ infinitely often we can construct a null sequence $(a_n)$ of bounded variation with the desired property by choosing a sufficiently fast (what is sufficiently fast depends on $(b_n)$) increasing sequence $(n_m)$ of positive integers and setting $a_n = b_m$ for $n_m < n \leqslant n_{m+1}$. Then
$$\sum_{n = n_{m-1}+1}^{n_m} \biggl(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = n}^{\infty} \lvert\Delta a_k\rvert^p\biggr)^{1/p} \geqslant \sum_{n = n_{m-1}+1}^{n_m} \frac{1}{n}\lvert\Delta a_{n_m}\rvert \sim \lvert\Delta b_m\rvert\log \frac{n_m}{n_{m-1}}$$
and we can choose $(n_m)$ such that
$$\sum_{m = 2}^{\infty} \lvert\Delta b_m\rvert\log \frac{n_m}{n_{m-1}} = +\infty\,.\tag{$\ast$}$$
As an example, let $b_m = \frac{1}{m}$ and $n_m = 2^{m(m-1)}$. Thus $\Delta b_m = \frac{1}{m(m+1)}$ and $\log (n_m/n_{m-1}) = (m-1)\log 4$, and $(\ast)$ diverges by comparison to the harmonic series.

Comment: See the edit please.

Comment: I just noticed that I didn't ping you yesterday. (And note that it isn't necessary to have $a_n$ constant on long intervals, that's just simpler to write down.)

Comment: Excellent answer, but can you please explain to me how do you take $\sum_{n = n_{m-1}+1}^{n_m} \frac{1}{n}\lvert\Delta a_{n_m}\rvert \sim \lvert\Delta b_m\rvert\log \frac{n_m}{n_{m-1}}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We have $\Delta a_{n_m} = \Delta b_m$ by construction ($a_{n_m} = b_m$, and $a_{n_m + 1} = a_{n_{m+1}} = b_{m+1}$), and that doesn't depend on the summation index, so we can take it out of the sum. And you probably know $\sum_{n = u+1}^v \frac{1}{n} = \log v - \log u + O(1) = \log \frac{v}{u} + O(1)$ very well. So $$\sum_{n = n_{m-1}+1}^{n_m} \frac{1}{n}\lvert\Delta a_{n_m}\rvert = \lvert \Delta b_m\rvert\cdot \biggl(\log \frac{n_m}{n_{m-1}} + O(1)\biggr) = \lvert\Delta b_m\rvert \log \frac{n_m}{n_{m-1}}\cdot \biggl(1 + O\biggl(\frac{1}{\log \frac{n_m}{n_{m-1}}}\biggr)\biggr)\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

The argument is:

We wish to prove $n|\Delta a_n|^p \leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} |\Delta a_k|^p$.

Now suppose that the right hand side does not contain at least $n$ terms of size $|\Delta a_n|^p$. Then surely $|\Delta a_k|^p \leq |\Delta a_n|^p$ eventually (i.e. of BV). If it does contain at least $n$ terms of this size, then the inequality holds, and again $a_n$ is of bounded variation as well.

Comment: I don't get how you conclude that $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is of BV from the inequality $|\Delta a_k|^p \leq |\Delta a_n|^p, \forall k\geq n.$

Comment: This is just the same as saying $|\Delta a_k| \leq M$ with $M = |\Delta a_n|$. Also of course, for $k<n$ there is a finite number of them to bound so those are bounded as well